# Change background color of ScrollBar in ScrollViewer wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, xaml, styles

I know how to change the background color of a scrollbar:

```
<ScrollBar Height="27" Margin="36,96,12,0" Name="scrollBar1" Background="Red"></ScrollBar>
```

here is the picture with my red background:
[image]

How could I do the same thing with ScrollViewer? I have a grid inside my ScrollViewer and if I change the properties of ScrollViewer it seem to change the properties of the content inside my grid.

```
<ScrollViewer>


    <Grid Name="Parent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
             ....
             ....
             ... etc
```

that produces:

[image]

with the content of my grid named Parent on the left. How could I place a red background on this ScrollViewer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the ScrollViewer style equal to a style that you build separately. Here are two links where the authors create a style first, and then apply said style to a wpf control after that:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37366/Styling-A-ScrollViewer-Scrollbar-In-WPF.aspx

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/f51ddf8c-5227-4f1b-a5df-ec3d1b3439ca/styling-the-wpf-scrollviewer.aspx

Answer (score 11):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

In the above code, the programmer can give any color value he/she wants to set.
For Eg, I have set the background color of my scrollbar to White.