# ListView Scrollbar Styling

Tags: wpf, listview, scrollbar

I am working on a WPF project. I need to customize the horizontal scrollbar of Listview,like reducing its height,changing background etc. How do I achieve this?

Using this, doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
 <ListView>
     <ListView.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="10"/>
         </Style>
     </ListView.Resources>
 </ListView>
```

Comment: Setting `Background` works for me in your style. `<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>`

Comment: yeah but how to reduce the height? Width,Background for horizontal Scrollbar are working but not able to reduce its height

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to modify the width and height of the bars, you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321247/how-to-increase-scrollbar-width-in-wpf-scrollviewer), which points you in the direction of using [`System.Windows.SystemParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.systemparameters.aspx) to modify those values.

However I think you require more complex styling (e.g. change the background) so I'm afraid you will need to play with control template parts. Check these two links (found in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527758/change-background-color-of-scrollbar-in-scrollviewer-wpf)):

- [Styling A ScrollViewer/Scrollbar In WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37366/Styling-A-ScrollViewer-Scrollbar-In-WPF)
- [Styling the WPF ScrollViewer](http://www.nullskull.com/a/1525/styling-the-wpf-scrollviewer.aspx)